# Why doesn't Immobilized grant Combat Advantage?

Tags: dnd-4e, combat-advantage, immobilized

In the list of effects, it seems immobilized is one of the few that *doesn't* grant combat advantage. I'm curious about the reasoning behind this. You're restricted to a small area and the Rules Compendium says that the player 'can't reposition itself on the battlegrid' and offers two examples, one, that it has a serious injury to it's legs, and two, that it's stuck in a giant spiderweb.

This sort of thing seems to be exactly the kind of stuff that would give an attacker a pretty significant advantage.

Comment: Note that there is a feat, Vicious Advantage, that lets you gain combat advantage against enemies that are slowed or immobilized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Immobilized is not Helpless/Restrained**

The reason Immobilized doesn't grant advantage is because it merely limits you to one location and does not actively stop you from performing any defense.  The fact is, being stuck in one square doesn't mean your entire body isn't usable, or that your senses are altered just yet. That's where other status effects jump in.  Someone tied up is Restrained, and all restrained critters are immobilized but not all immobilized critters are restrained.

Comment: Additionally, an immobilized character is limited to his or her square.  Recall that a square in 'real world' terms is 5 feet by 5 feet.  This still gives you a fair amount of space to actively defend yourself.

Comment: While your explanation clarifies the rules, it doesn't explain the rationale. Particularly based on the examples given. Being glued to the floor by a buncha webs is at the very least make it next to impossible turn to face anyone. I'd think that one'd be just as effective at defending while blinded as when stapled to the floor. But still, thanks for the clarifying. Rules gotta rule sometimes.

Comment: Being glued to the floor by webs would probably be restrained, not immobilized. Also, D&D 4e is a game system before a fantasy combat simulator, so conditions are primarily given value in terms of game function. There are often "softer" versions of most penalties (eg: slowed -> immobilized -> restrained, dazed -> stunned -> unconscious) with varying degrees of in-game effect balanced on game function before "reality simulation."